# python pyramid mongo and wsgi : "Cannot connect to the database" in production

Tags: python, configuration, mongodb, pyramid, dotcloud

I trying to run a pyramid+mongodb at dotcloud with this wsgi.py

```
import os, sys
from paste.deploy import loadapp
current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
application = loadapp('config:production.ini', relative_to=current_dir)
```

production.ini

```
mongodb.url = mongodb://root:PASSWORD@sarasa.dotcloud.com:18145
mongodb.db_name = my_data_base
```

**error** : "Cannot connect to the database"

at localhost is working,at production.ini only change mongodb.url

Answer (score 1):

Your URI should look like this:

mongodb://root:PASSWORD@sarasa.dotcloud.com:18145/my_data_base

Comment: still gives the  "Cannot connect to the database". any other idea? thanks a lot anyway